# Is it faster to use one large EXPR in tcl rather than several small ones

Tags: performance, tcl

I have a proc which gets executed a couple of hundred thousand times:

```
proc ::TsaiWu { x_all_comp x_all_tens y_all_comp y_all_tens s_allow x_stress y_stress s_stress } {

        set FX  [ expr { 1 / $x_all_tens - 1 / $x_all_tens } ]
        set FY  [ expr { 1 / $y_all_tens - 1 / $y_all_tens } ] 
        set FXX [ expr { 1 / ( $x_all_tens * $x_all_comp ) } ]
        set FYY [ expr { 1 / ( $y_all_tens * $y_all_comp ) } ]
        set IXY [ expr { -0.5 * sqrt( ( $y_all_tens * $y_all_comp) / ( $x_all_tens * $x_all_comp) ) } ]
        set FXY [ expr { $IXY / sqrt( $x_all_tens * $x_all_comp * $y_all_tens * $y_all_comp ) } ]
        set FSS [ expr { 1 / pow($s_allow,2) } ]
        set a   [ expr { $FXX * pow($x_stress,2) + $FYY * pow($y_stress,2) + 2 * $FXY * $x_stress * $y_stress + $FSS * pow($s_stress,2) } ]
        set b   [ expr { $FX * $x_stress + $FY * $y_stress } ]
        set TW  [ expr { $a + $b } ]
        set SR  [ expr { ( -2 + sqrt( pow($b,2) + 4 * $a) ) / ( 2 * $a ) } ]

        set result [ list $TW $SR ] 

    return $result

 }
```

What possibilties do I have to speed it up? I have added curly brackets to the expression, that did help a lot.. Is it faster to rewrite the single equations into just two (one for TW and one for SR) ?
Then I would only need to call expr twice. Would it be faster if i wrote this piece of code in c++ and somehow use in my tcl script? Is there a speed difference between sqrt and pow(x,0.5) ? Any tips on how to speed this proc upp are welcome!
In the final version i will use upvar or a global variable so I dont't have to hand over the result as a list copy (is it much slower?) Would the code run faster if I would not put these lines in a proc by itselv, and insted place it "inline" the code where it is needed? As far as I know procs are faster in TCl...

Comment: A few suggestions: why don't you try both and time them? FX and FY are always zero.

Comment: [`time`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/time.htm) them.

Comment: If you call this proc that often, I suggest that you rewrite it using C and expose it as Tcl extension. Hey, something to do for me this evening. (I never wrote an Tcl extension but it doesn't sound hard.)

Comment: I have just timed them: Reducing the call of expr reduces execution time by 1/3 from 3000 microsec to 2000 microsec. Compiling the procs to *.tbc reduced time per execution to 117 microsec ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you *brace* your expressions (**important!**) and use just local variables, it makes very little difference. The cost of reading and writing a local variable is minimal, not much more than reading and writing a variable in C. The real costs of execution will mainly be in the arithmetic operations and the function calls; it is those that you should minimize (while retaining correctness, of course).

Specific issues: You might find that using `$b**2` or `$b*$b` is cheaper than `pow($b,2)`. The `sqrt()` calls are likely to be expensive; can you reduce the number that you do? (Note that `pow(…,0.5)` is unlikely to be better, and might possibly be worse in terms of numerical accuracy.)

Generic issues: Changing the build of Tcl can have quite a big effect. I found a few weeks ago that switching from the system build of 8.5.9 to my own (made with an up-to-date LLVM/Clang) made a substantial improvement to speeds, *yet with the identical source code and identical scripts*. Funny how these things go…

If you're really hurting for time, try writing a little C code to implement the math. That will probably be faster (and will allow you to use `float` instead of being forced to use `double`, which is what Tcl uses internally for floating-point numbers) but I don't know how much faster. If you're doing this, you'll find the API calls `Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj` and `Tcl_NewDoubleObj` to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you use tcl::unsupported::disassemble to examine the bytecode
of the proc, you will see that one [expr] vs many [expr] makes no
difference at all.

When you [time] make sure to test a large number of iterations so
that you measure the run time, and not the compile-to-bytecode time
which happens only once.

Your concern about "list copy" on return is unfounded. That's not
how Tcl works.  Toying with [upvar] to solve a "problem" you do 
not actually have is not a path you want to take.

Using a global
variable will slow your proc down, possibly measurably.  You want
your [expr]essions in a proc so they can operate on local vars,
where the speed gains of bytecode are the greatest.